# Annotate a tikzpicture node with multiple-line legend

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am not fully green with Tikz. What I would like to achieve is to annotate two nodes with multiple-line math.
I am dealing with the following figure:
[image]

In place of the annotations, I would like to place the following legends:
[image]
[image]

Here is my MWE. It maybe trivial but not straightforward for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
% dpic version 2019.11.30 option -g for TikZ and PGF 1.01
\ifx\dpiclw\undefined\newdimen\dpiclw\fi
\global\def\dpicdraw{\draw[line width=\dpiclw]}
\global\def\dpicstop{;}
\dpiclw=0.8bp
\dpiclw=0.8bp
\dpicdraw (0,0)
 --(0,0.8125)\dpicstop
\dpicdraw (0,0.9375) circle (0.049213in)\dpicstop
\filldraw[line width=0bp](0.025,0.93125)
 --(0,1.03125)
 --(-0.025,0.93125) --cycle\dpicstop
\dpicdraw (0,0.84375)
 --(0,1.008344)\dpicstop
\dpicdraw (0,1.0625)
 --(0,1.875)\dpicstop
\draw (0,1.0625) node[above right=-2bp]{$ +$};
\draw (-0.125,0.9375) node[left=2bp]{$\mathrm{I_{\mathit{Nor}}}=-0.2111-j0.5138\,\SI{}{\ampere}$};
\dpicdraw (-0.005556,1.875)
 --(1.505556,1.875)\dpicstop
\dpicdraw[fill=black](1.505556,1.875) circle (0.007874in)\dpicstop
\dpicdraw (1.505556,1.875)
 --(1.505556,1.1875)\dpicstop
\global\let\dpicshdraw=\dpicdraw\global\def\dpicdraw{}
\global\def\dpicstop{--}
\dpicshdraw[fill=white]
\dpicdraw (1.505556,0.6875)
 --(1.655556,0.6875)
 --(1.655556,1.1875)
 --(1.355556,1.1875)
 --(1.355556,0.6875)
 --(1.505556,0.6875)\dpicstop
cycle; \global\let\dpicdraw=\dpicshdraw\global\def\dpicstop{;}
\dpicdraw (1.505556,0.6875)
 --(1.505556,0)\dpicstop
\draw (1.655556,0.9375) node[right=2bp]{$\mathrm{Z_{\mathit{Nor}}}=0.130-j7.496\,\SI{}{\ohm}$};
\dpicdraw[fill=black](1.505556,0) circle (0.007874in)\dpicstop
\dpicdraw (1.505556,1.875)
 --(3.005556,1.875)\dpicstop
\draw (3.005556,1.875) node[right=-2bp]{$A$};
\dpicdraw[fill=black](3.005556,1.875) circle (0.007874in)\dpicstop
\dpicdraw[fill=black](3.005556,0) circle (0.007874in)\dpicstop
\draw (3.005556,0) node[right=-2bp]{$B$};
\dpicdraw (3.011111,0)
 --(-0.005556,0)\dpicstop
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `aligned` environment from `amsmath` for that:

```
$\begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{I_{\mathit{Nor}}} &= \SI{-0.2111-j0.5138}{\ampere} \\
                            &= abc
\end{aligned}$
```

Note that if you want to write just a unit, use `\si{<unit>}` instead of `\SI{}{<unit>}`. Here I put the number in the first argument to `\SI`. While the default output is not similar to your example, you can change that with

```
\sisetup{
  multi-part-units=single,
  output-complex-root=\ensuremath{\mathrm{j}},
  complex-root-position=before-number
}
```

Add this to the preamble if you want this setting to the entire document, or just after `\begin{tikzpicture}` to modify it just for the diagram.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\sisetup{
  multi-part-units=single,
  output-complex-root=\ensuremath{\mathrm{j}},
  complex-root-position=before-number
}

% dpic version 2019.11.30 option -g for TikZ and PGF 1.01
\ifx\dpiclw\undefined\newdimen\dpiclw\fi
\global\def\dpicdraw{\draw[line width=\dpiclw]}
\global\def\dpicstop{;}
\dpiclw=0.8bp
\dpiclw=0.8bp
\dpicdraw (0,0)
 --(0,0.8125)\dpicstop
\dpicdraw (0,0.9375) circle (0.049213in)\dpicstop
\filldraw[line width=0bp](0.025,0.93125)
 --(0,1.03125)
 --(-0.025,0.93125) --cycle\dpicstop
\dpicdraw (0,0.84375)
 --(0,1.008344)\dpicstop
\dpicdraw (0,1.0625)
 --(0,1.875)\dpicstop
\draw (0,1.0625) node[above right=-2bp]{$ +$};
\draw (-0.125,0.9375) node[left=2bp] {%
  $  \begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{I_{\mathit{Nor}}} &= \SI{-0.2111-j0.5138}{\ampere} \\
                            &= abc
  \end{aligned}$};
\dpicdraw (-0.005556,1.875)
 --(1.505556,1.875)\dpicstop
\dpicdraw[fill=black](1.505556,1.875) circle (0.007874in)\dpicstop
\dpicdraw (1.505556,1.875)
 --(1.505556,1.1875)\dpicstop
\global\let\dpicshdraw=\dpicdraw\global\def\dpicdraw{}
\global\def\dpicstop{--}
\dpicshdraw[fill=white]
\dpicdraw (1.505556,0.6875)
 --(1.655556,0.6875)
 --(1.655556,1.1875)
 --(1.355556,1.1875)
 --(1.355556,0.6875)
 --(1.505556,0.6875)\dpicstop
cycle; \global\let\dpicdraw=\dpicshdraw\global\def\dpicstop{;}
\dpicdraw (1.505556,0.6875)
 --(1.505556,0)\dpicstop
\draw (1.655556,0.9375) node[right=2bp]{%
$\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Z_{\mathit{Nor}}} &= \SI{0.130-j7.496}{\ohm} \\
                           &= def
\end{aligned}$};
\dpicdraw[fill=black](1.505556,0) circle (0.007874in)\dpicstop
\dpicdraw (1.505556,1.875)
 --(3.005556,1.875)\dpicstop
\draw (3.005556,1.875) node[right=-2bp]{$A$};
\dpicdraw[fill=black](3.005556,1.875) circle (0.007874in)\dpicstop
\dpicdraw[fill=black](3.005556,0) circle (0.007874in)\dpicstop
\draw (3.005556,0) node[right=-2bp]{$B$};
\dpicdraw (3.011111,0)
 --(-0.005556,0)\dpicstop
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason the simpler solution `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}` does not work.

Comment: @user202729 No, it wouldn't. `align*`  sets the math in a separate paragraph I believe, and it needs to have a defined width of the text block, as in normal text on a page. In a node, by default, there is no defined text block. If you add `text width=4cm` to the node options, this makes the node a `minipage` like construct, and then `align*` does work. However. that will give you an empty line at the start of the node, add `draw` to see that. In https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsRXO.png `aligned` is used on the left, and `align*` on the right.

Comment: @user202729 I would say that while `align*` perhaps looks simpler, it is also the wrong method to use in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that with `circuitikz` is drawing of the your scheme simpler:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  multi-part-units=single,
  output-complex-root=\ensuremath{\mathrm{j}},
  complex-root-position=before-number
        }
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=9mm}
\draw (0,0)  to[isource, name=i,
                l=\footnotesize
               ${\begin{array}{r@{\,}l}
                I_{\text{Nor}}  & = \SI{0.130-j7.496}{\ohm}\\
                                & = 0.555\phase{-112.33}\,\si{\ampere}
                 \end{array}}$]   (0,2) 
             to[short, -*] (2,2) 
             to[short, -*] (5,2) node[right] {$A$}
       (2,2) to[R=\footnotesize
                ${\begin{array}{r@{\,}l}   
                Z_{\text{Nor}}  & = \SI{0.130-j7.496}{\ohm}\\
                                & = 7.497\phase{0.89}\,\si{\ohm}
                  \end{array}}$] (2,0) -- (0,0)
       (2,0) to[short,*-*] (5,0) node[right] {$B$};
\node[above right] at (i.east) {+};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed. circuitikz is definitely much easier but I don't appreciate its drawing of the two-terminal elements by default. The size of the resistor is for example too big for my taste. So, it's more of of personal preference, hence my choice of circuit_macros.

Comment: @billyandriam, size of two terminal elemets can be easy set (for example with `\ctikzset{bipoles//length=9mm}` (added now in answer.). Also the way of drawing is simple to adjust o consistent way (now is on American style, but with replace `american`  to `european`, the scheme will change elements to European style). However, how you will draw, is up top you.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit and for the hack. I will definitely have a look at it every now and then.